# Crystal Report total on non-displayed values

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

I have a report which displays the terminated employees for a specific date range.  I am trying to create a total of the then active employees to be able to generate a turnover rate.  I am only displaying those employees who have terminated for any reason.  My record selection pulls all employees active or inactive within the specified date range. For display I am using:

```
{@Terminated}=False.
```

I am struggling with how I can get a total of the active employees for the specified date range end date.  I have grouped the records on Employer Code.  Is there a method by which I can count these non-displayed "active" employees within the date range?

Comment: Do you need running total (calculated from displayed values) or just total (is not limited to displayed values, can be inserted anywhere in group header or footer)?

Comment: I am trying to find the overall total of active employees within a specified date range.  For example the entire file may contain 1,000 records and I specify the year 2014 and from that I can determine that at the end date (12/31/2014) I have 235 active employees I am needing to create the total for finding the 235 count.  My selection has found that I have 55 terminated employees during that year.  Given that some of those 235 may have terminated in 2015 I created a filter.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need count of all employees, matching record selection criteria? Then just right-click on any unique employee field in report, select Insert - Summary, choose Count for function and Report Footer (or header or wherever you need this value placed) for location and that should be all.

Comment: From my 1000 employee file I selected all employees within a date range as my first selection (be they active or terminated) then my report was created to display only those that met the "terminated" criteria.  I am able to get counts on these displayed employees but unable to find a method for counting the remaining employees from the first selection of employees within the date range.  I am not displaying the "active" employees in my report.  My end objective is to calculate the #terminated/#active to arrive at my turnover rate.

Comment: This was my selection criteria where my filter sought the value of this field >= 1      if isnull({vHEmployee.TermDate}) then 2 else

if{?Service_Length}=1 then (if{vHEmployee.AdjSeniorityDate}<={?End Date} and
 {vHEmployee.TermDate}>= {?Start Date} then 1) else

if{?Service_Length}=2 then (if({vHEmployee.OriginalHireDate}<={?End Date} and  
 {vHEmployee.TermDate}>= {?Start Date}) then 1) else
 
if{?Service_Length}=3 then (if{vHEmployee.LastHireDate}<={?End Date} and
 {vHEmployee.TermDate}>= {?Start Date} then 1) else 0